# Load Scene when Enemy Collides with Player-Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Unity 2D. I am trying to load EndGameScene when an enemy collides with my player, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My tags are "Player" and "enemy".
This is the  [current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znawO.png).

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class EndGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy")
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene("EndGameScene");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This script is attached to the player, correct?

Comment: I have it attached to Player and 3 enemies. Should I just have it attached to player?

Comment: You should only have it attached to the player, unless you want the game to end when the enemies collide with each other. Also check the name of your scene. All caps GAME OVER isn't really a conventional name.

Comment: Hi @drewb33, you should post code instead of animage, specialy if it is an external image, which may not be available in the future.

Comment: I made sure it was added to just player, switched the scene name to EndGameScene, and posted the code in the comments for my EndGame. Still no luck

Comment: You were correct in the first place, not sure why you changed the condition to check for name instead. Also are there any errors or does it just not work?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]. this is [tag:c#] code

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Unity (and it's been some time since last time I used it), so this check list may be incomplete, but still worth a try:

- Put a `Debug.Log("it collides!")` at the beggining of your OnCollisionEnter function, so you can be sure that it is actually detecting a collition.

If it doesn't print anything:

- Check if you are ussing a collider in both the player and the enemies.
- The player's collider should have the "Is trigger" checkbox selected, so it triggers a OncollitionEnter event.

If it prints the message:

- Check if there is an error message under the printer message, may be that it can't find the scene.
- Be sure that you typed correctly the name/tag of the enemies (I suppose the script is on your player)

Answer (score 0):

there's a better way to make the collision:
change the name here `if (collision.gameObject.name == "enemy")`
and make it like this `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")`
and go to the enemys in you scene and add the Enemy tag to them

Comment: Tag is definitely the way to go here. This is wrong.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that names are used to identify a particular object and tags are used to identify a type of object.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have not built the scene into the project's build settings (in the unity interface):

> Go to the Game Over scene/ open it by going to File>OpenScene>Scenes(folder)>Game Over (scene name)
> click 'File' (top left corner)
> click 'Build Settings' option
> click 'Add Open Scenes button'
> make sure the scene you want to add is listed and checked
> click 'Build' (on bottom right)